# Design lookup table in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to design EAV database for my website. Here are tables

```
 Category
-------------------------
|   Id  |   Title       |
|-----------------------|
|   1   |   Supplier    |
|   2   |   Material    |
|   3   |   RAM         |
|   4   |   CPU         |
|   5   |   Product     |
-------------------------

Item
-------------------------
|   Id  |   Category_Id |
|-----------------------|
|   1   |   1           |
|   2   |   1           |
|   3   |   1           |
|   4   |   2           |
|   5   |   2           |
|   6   |   3           |
|   7   |   3           |
|   8   |   4           |
|   9   |   4           |
|   10  |   4           |
|   11  |   5           |
|   12  |   5           |
-------------------------

AttributeType
-------------------------
|   Id  |   Title       |
|-----------------------|
|   1   |   String      |
|   2   |   Text        |
|   3   |   Number      |
|   4   |   Lookup      |
-------------------------

Attribute
-------------------------
|   Id  |   Title       |
|-----------------------|
|   1   |   Name        |
|   2   |   Price       |
|   3   |   Suplier     |
|   4   |   RAM         |
|   5   |   CPU         |
|   6   |   Material    |
|   7   |   Address     |
-------------------------

AttributeStringValue
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   Id  |   Attribute_Id    |   Item_Id     |   Value           |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|   1   |   1               |       1       |   Samsung         |
|   2   |   1               |       2       |   Nokia           |
|   3   |   1               |       3       |   Dell            |
|   4   |   1               |       4       |   Steal           |
|   5   |   1               |       5       |   Plastic         |
|   6   |   1               |       6       |   Ram 8GB         |
|   7   |   1               |       7       |   Ram 16GB        |
|   8   |   1               |       8       |   Core I3         |
|   9   |   1               |       9       |   Core I5         |
|   10  |   1               |       10      |   Core I7         |
|   11  |   1               |       11      |   Mobile Nokia 1  |
|   12  |   1               |       12      |   Laptop Dell 1   |
|   13  |   7               |       1       |   Korea           |
|   14  |   7               |       2       |   Finland         |
|   15  |   7               |       3       |   USA             |
-----------------------------------------------------------------

AttributeNumberValue
-----------------------------------------------------------------
|   Id  |   Attribute_Id    |   Item_Id     |   Value           |
|---------------------------------------------------------------|
|   1   |   1               |       11      |   100             |
|   2   |   1               |       12      |   500             |
-----------------------------------------------------------------
```

I want Mobile Nokia 1 and Laptop Dell 1 have supplier names that are lookuped to the items that have category is Supplier and I can config display column.

Ex:
Supplier have values: Nokia (address: Finland), Samsung(address: Korea)
"Mobile Nokia 1" has supplier column is items in the supplier category and I can configure to display "Address" column or "Title" column of supplier

Please give me advise to design lookup tables

Sorry for my english

Many thanks

Comment: See [Five Simple Database Design Errors You Should Avoid (point #3)](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/five-simple--database-design-errors-you-should-avoid/) for a discussion of why EAV is really really bad, and see [Bad CaRMa](https://www.simple-talk.com/content/article.aspx?article=292) for a true horror story of an EAV system design that ruined a thriving company.

Comment: Idf you want to implement this constraint...... then I recommend you actually go back to a non-EAV model. Because there's no such thing as a "filtered" Foreign Key definition. You can try and enforce this with triggers and stored procedures but it's the "tail wagging the dog"

Comment: Bad carma is a great read, and I would say over engineering exists to this day (try writing a sensible query over Data Vault)

Comment: Thank all, maybe I will use JSON data to store attribute

Comment: Not sure why you think JSON is going to help, if anything it will make it worse. Unless you mean to store all the attributes together, in which case your only gain is lookup performance on a whole entity, at the cost of lookup performance per attribute

Comment: @Charlieface, I will store attributes value in the JSON string as a field in  the"Item" table

Comment: As mentioned: that will get you a performance gain for looking up one `Item`, at a huge cost for looking up all the data for one `Attribute`. Whereas if it was a proper normalized table, you could index it both ways round

Comment: @Charlieface can you advise me on the best practice to design flexibility database

Comment: Very hard to say: there are so many ways to cut this. If you need proper referential integrity or check constraints, dynamically adding columns and constraints is the best, but can be difficult to manage in terms of application code. JSON or XML is a good option if you always retrieve single records. EAV tables can be good if you want to look up all of a single attribute.